# Why does my count not increase as intended?

Tags: react-hooks

In the below code, when I click increase twice, the count increases by 2. However, after 5 sec, it decreases by 1 then increases by 2 instead of simply increasing by 1, as intended. Here's the code:-

```
 const Counter=()=>{
    const [count, setCount]=useState(0)
    setTimeout(()=>{
    setCount(count+1)
    }, 5000)

   return(<>
  <button onClick={()=>setCount(()=>count+1)}>Increase</button>
  <h2>{count}</h2>
 </>
)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is where the [functional pattern](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) of setState comes in handy. If the new value of state depends on the previous value, this pattern is recommended to have accurate computations.

Change your increase function like:

```
    setCount((count) => count + 1);
```

Here is a [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-dawn-6i8rhj?file=/src/App.js:178-214)

**Note:** You are setting state directly inside your main function body so this is probably going to cause a lot fo rerenders. Every time the component renders a new timeout is set, and every timeout will cause a state update and hence a render. You can change your approach probably